# (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") in many-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, eloquent-relationship

I'm try to create `many-to-many` that link with `customer` and `shop` in laravel but stuck in this error `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")` and still, not figure it out.

Here my `customers` table

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('email');
  $table->string('phone');
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shop');
});
```

Here my `shops` table

```
Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customer');
});
```

My `Shop` Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function customer()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Customer::class);
}
```

My `Customer` Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone'];

public function shop()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Shop::class);
}
```

Any Help? Thanks in advances....

Answer (score 3):

Check your Schema - 
Its should be shops not shop...

```
$table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
```

and similarly customers not customer...

```
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Comment: Try it ---  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop', 'shop_id');

Comment: @CamBoKiDz are you trying 2 tables foreign at a same time?

Answer (score 0):

Note for you. Don't use foreign command in table create command together.
Make sure always new migration file for adding foreign key's inside table. 
Cause sometime its generate Errors while migrating ..
open your bash shell or PHP Storm Terminal or CMD

```
php artisan make:migration foreign_customer_id_at_table_shops --table=shops //you Can use your own migration name what you want
```

at foreign_customer_id_at_table_shops migration file

## UP

```
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

## DOWN

```
$table->dropForeign(['customer_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the foreign key in relationship rather than in migration.

```
 public function customer()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Customer::class','id','shop_id');
 }

 public function shop()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Shop::class','id','customer_id');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation of many-to-many need third table `pivot` table which you miss it.
for do that create new migration.
`php artisan make:migration create_customer_shop`

> there is no need create model for pivot table

then you Schema pivot table something like this.
**Pivot table**

```
Schema::create('cutomer_shop', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
  $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned();
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
  $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
});
```

The two table `shops` and `customers` doesn't have any direct relations they have relation by just pivot table.
**Note:** make sure all three table id type `increments('id')` and all foreign key are `$table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned();` otherwise give you incorrect format error.